# T4MVC unit test generator

Tags: c#, code-generation, t4mvc

Is there in existence a TT file to generate unit tests for the generated output from t4mvc?

If there isn't I may need to make one. Unless this is completely stupid? The co i work for are pretty much saying I need to get our generated code tested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm the author/maintainer of T4MVC, and I have not heard of such thing around, so my guess is that it doesn't exist.

Note that the T4MVC generated code has CompilerGenerated attributes that should cause it to be excluded from standard test coverage metrics.

It should still be possible to generate unit tests for it if you really wanted that. :)